# initialize java library after installing as extension in XWIki

Tags: java, initialization, listener, xwiki

We have designed a listener for XWiki in java and are installing it using the extension manager. Is there any code that's run on install? We would like to register the listener immediately and not wait for the first instantiation of the component.

The XWiki version is 6.4.7.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to Component descriptor registration events in another listener. For example [`ComponentDescriptorAddedEvent`](https://github.com/xwiki/xwiki-commons/blob/b257f3534d3cdbc07b745e8729d3c302da7ce050/xwiki-commons-core/xwiki-commons-component/xwiki-commons-component-observation/src/main/java/org/xwiki/component/event/ComponentDescriptorAddedEvent.java#L37-L37).

See also http://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/Component+Module#HComponentEvents for a bit more details.

Comment: So this means adding another listener. Since the listeners are not able to listen to Wikibased events, this means one (1) listener that is triggering the various custom listeners as we have designed? Sounds like a plan :-) I will look into it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If your listener is a Java component (as in a component implementing org.xwiki.observation.EventListener) it is immediately registered.

Comment: No it isn't. I have created my own listener class based on the EventListener class since I need to have more control over the events and need to ensure it only listens to a specified Wiki (at least he needs to stop listening when it's an event fired from any other Wiki then his own.

Comment: You are probably mixing things here. A component implementing EventListener is registered automatically by the observation manager when receiving ComponentDescriptorAddedEvent event (event which is registered when a component is installed). If you make your listener implement org.xwiki.component.phase.Initializable you will see that initialize() is called during install. If what you want is to have your event listener be "called" and not just "registered" then you can listen for example to ExtensionInstalledEvent or ExtensionUpgradedEvent events.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. This is very helpful and I will definitelty implement this suggestion.